# How do I get rid of "Body:" as highlighted bellow?

Tags: theming, nodes

[image: Can Some one please help me out get rid of this "Body:" from the top of my content in Drupal as it is getting some what annoying]

what can be done to get rid of highlighted section from the top of content?

Comment: goto Structure -> your-content-type -> manage display and hide body label.

Answer (score 1):

- Login as Administrator
- Go to admin/structure/types
- Click on Manage Fields next to above content content type..

[image]

- Click on Mange Display
- Hide Body label like shown below..

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation